# ng-strict-di doesn't recognise 'ngInject'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ng-annotate

I'm using Rails 4.0 with AngularJS 1.5 and the ng-annotate gem. I've noticed that when I put on the 'ng-strict-di' which forces you to annotate all your direct injections in AngularJS I find that Rails complains about modules which have "ngInject" in place.

eg; Here is my application controller for Angular

```
ApplicationController = (
  $scope, $timeout,
  hotkeys
  ShortcutService) ->
  "ngInject"
<SNIP>
```

I have ng-strict-di enabled in my template

```
<html ng-app='paisApp' ng-strict-di>
```

When I run my application in dev mode I get an error in the console;

```
Error: [$injector:strictdi] ApplicationController is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.11/$injector/strictdi?p0=ApplicationController
minErr/<@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular.self.js?body=1:69:12
annotate@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular.self.js?body=1:4006:17
injectionArgs@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular.self.js?body=1:4733:21
instantiate@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular.self.js?body=1:4784:18
$controller@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular.self.js?body=1:10608:18
controllerDecorator/<@http://localhost:3000/assets/app/bower_components/angular-material-data-table/dist/md-data-table.self.js?body=1:321:12
compile/<@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.self.js?body=1:9781:46
bind/<@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular.self.js?body=1:1260:15
invokeLinkFn@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular.self.js?body=1:10153:9
nodeLinkFn@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular.self.js?body=1:9552:11
compositeLinkFn@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular.self.js?body=1:8811:13
publicLinkFn@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular.self.js?body=1:8691:30
lazyCompilation@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular.self.js?body=1:9048:16
updateView@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.self.js?body=1:9719:38
configUpdatedCallback@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.self.js?body=1:9663:25
configureUIView@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.self.js?body=1:5640:17
ViewService.prototype.sync@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.self.js?body=1:5645:9
activateViews@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.self.js?body=1:6273:5
invokeCallback@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.self.js?body=1:1580:20
TransitionHook.prototype.invokeHook@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.self.js?body=1:1592:26
TransitionHook.runAllHooks/<@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.self.js?body=1:1719:48
TransitionHook.runAllHooks@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.self.js?body=1:1719:9
transitionSuccess@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.self.js?body=1:3432:13
processQueue@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular.self.js?body=1:16697:28
scheduleProcessQueue/<@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular.self.js?body=1:16713:27
$eval@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular.self.js?body=1:17995:16
$digest@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular.self.js?body=1:17809:15
$apply@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular.self.js?body=1:18103:13
done@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular.self.js?body=1:12083:36
completeRequest@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular.self.js?body=1:12292:7
requestLoaded@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular/angular.self.js?body=1:12220:9
 <div id="wrapper" ui-view="" class="ng-scope" data-ng-animate="1">
angular.self.js:14200:18
```

If I manually annotate this then the error goes away, for that file. I have a lot of angularJS files so I don't want to do this for each one.

**Update**

I'm running my server with NG_FORCE=true like so;

```
NG_FORCE=true RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rails s
```